# Laravel query data from DB to view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller, laravel-query-builder

i have DB table name match_facts where is displayed data about every match player.

```
id  match_id    player_id   minutes goals
```

i need them to display in view.
should i need to put them in array?

```
    $match_facts = Match_fact::where('match_id', $match->id);
```

Comment: You should at least use `->get()` or `->paginate()` to get any results. Not sure what you mean by "_should i need to put them in array?_"

Comment: @brombeer, ohh.. just forgot ->get() , thanks